# How perform "Go To Definition" in Visual Studio without using mouse click

Tags: visual-studio, shortcut, go-to-definition, code-navigation

I would like to perform Go To Definition without taking hands off the keyboard. Is it possible to change [Ctrl + Left Click] to [Ctrl + AnyKey] when cursor hover the target?

Comment: F12 is still there from the days of Vs2003 (perhaps even 2002 but I haven't used it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The F12 keyboard shortcut serves as Go To Definition for where the cursor is at. Of course, if you right click on it...it would conveniently show you the keyboard shortcut.

[image]